# Add column in ASCII that is calculated from existing column

Tags: python, ascii, calculated-columns

I have an ascii file that contains two columns. I need to add two more columns. The output textfile should contain those two columns and the original two in brackets separated by comma. Opening the ascii in gedit, my input file looks like this:

```
1  2
3  4
5  6
7  8
```

in the end I want it to be like this:

```
2 6 (1,2)
6 12 (3,4)
10 18 (5,6)
14 24 (7,8)
```

so that my two new columns are a multiple of two/ three of the original ones. I've only come as far as reading in the file as a pandas dataframe and already was confused

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.txt")
print(df)

       1  2
0      3  4
1      5  6
2      7  8
```

The pandas dataframe that I want to output to ascii is supposed to have this structure:

```
     2 6 (1   2)
0    6 12 (3   4)
1    10 18 (5   6)
2    14 24 (7   8)
```

I don't even know how to start because I completely don't understand the structure etc. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should run your code in a debugger, stop on the `print(df)` line, and really look at `df` and figure out what you really have there.  Alternately, read the Pandas documentation until you understand what you've got that way.  Replace `print(df)` with code that extracts values from `df` and prints them.  This can't be very hard to figure out.

Comment: Someone can probably help you more directly with Pandas.  I don't use it.  But if I were you, I wouldn't ask here for such basic information.  I'd just figure it out for myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file without pandas:

```
we=open('new.txt','w')
with open('read.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
#read a line
         a,b=line.split('\t')
#get two values as string
         c=2*int(a)
         d=3*int(b)
#calculate the other two values
         ### edited
         e = ''.join(("(",str(a),",",str(b),")"))
         print(e)
         ####

         #e=str(tuple(a,b))
         #we.write(str(c)+' '+str(d)+e+'\n'
#write to new file
```

Hope this helps